# How to use javascript for an element whose id is defined as a php function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am building a website and in one of the pages,i am using a php function to define id of element.The reason is,that element is repeated and id should be unique and javascript can also work according to change in element .The problem i am having is,i cannot define javascript function according to change in element id.
This is the code:
**HTML PART:**

```
<div id="star1s<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="rating"></div>
```

Here in html part,the_ID() is the php function which changes the element id to make the element id unique.
So for example,if the_ID() returns 11, the div id becomes stars1s11.
Here is the javascript part: 
**JAVASCRIPT PART:**

```
 var getstarid = "<?php the_ID();?>";

function rating1(stars) {
  var ratingfill = stars;
  var rating_integer = Math.floor(ratingfill);
  var rating_decimal = ratingfill % 1;
  var rating_dec_trimmed = rating_decimal.toFixed(1);
  if ((rating_dec_trimmed == 0.1) || (rating_dec_trimmed == 0.2) ||
    (rating_dec_trimmed == 0.3) || (rating_dec_trimmed == 0.4)) {
    rate1.style.width = ((40 * rating_integer) + 18) + 'px';
  }
  if ((rating_dec_trimmed == 0.6) || (rating_dec_trimmed == 0.7) ||
    (rating_dec_trimmed == 0.8) || (rating_dec_trimmed == 0.9)) {
    rate1.style.width = ((40 * rating_integer) + 28) + 'px';
  }
  if (rating_dec_trimmed == 0.5) {
    rate1.style.width = ((40 * rating_integer) + 20) + 'px';
  }
  if (rating_dec_trimmed == 0) {
    rate1.style.width = (40 * rating_integer) + 'px';
  }
}
var getrate1 = "<?php echo $ratingonequery;?>";
rating1(getrate1);
```

In the Javascript part,i want to replace "rate1" in "rate1.style.width" with the corresponding id according to php function the_ID().So,for example if the_ID() returns 11 the id should be star1s11

I will also share style
**STYLE PART:**

```
.rating {
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #0095f9;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rating::before {
  content: "\2605\2605\2605\2605\2605"
}
```

I will also put a **screenshot of the output.**
This code is used for displaying stars according to user value fetched from the database.

[image: Screenshot of the output when]

Thanking in advance.

Comment: replace `rate1` with `document.getElementById("star1s"+getstarid)`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: What's in your javascript console if you hit F12?

Comment: If this is being displayed from a database why the need for JS? Wouldn't it be easier to use PHP and some CSS classes?

Comment: @LennartHase Yes,your solution is correct.Post it as an answer so that i can mark it as correct and also upvote.Also good for Stackoverflow community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you're looking to do you should replace `rate1` with `document.getElementById("star1s"+getstarid)`, where `getstarid` is the star id as defined in your PHP. So your javascript code should look like this:

```
var getstarid = "<?php the_ID();?>";

function rating1(stars) {
  var ratingfill = stars;
  var rating_integer = Math.floor(ratingfill);
  var rating_decimal = ratingfill % 1;
  var rating_dec_trimmed = rating_decimal.toFixed(1);
  if ((rating_dec_trimmed == 0.1) || (rating_dec_trimmed == 0.2) ||
    (rating_dec_trimmed == 0.3) || (rating_dec_trimmed == 0.4)) {
    document.getElementById("star1s"+getstarid).style.width = ((40 * rating_integer) + 18) + 'px';
  }
  if ((rating_dec_trimmed == 0.6) || (rating_dec_trimmed == 0.7) ||
    (rating_dec_trimmed == 0.8) || (rating_dec_trimmed == 0.9)) {
    document.getElementById("star1s"+getstarid).style.width = ((40 * rating_integer) + 28) + 'px';
  }
  if (rating_dec_trimmed == 0.5) {
    document.getElementById("star1s"+getstarid).style.width = ((40 * rating_integer) + 20) + 'px';
  }
  if (rating_dec_trimmed == 0) {
    document.getElementById("star1s"+getstarid).style.width = (40 * rating_integer) + 'px';
  }
}
var getrate1 = "<?php echo $ratingonequery;?>";
rating1(getrate1);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping.